Issues with Dax formulas with dates in Power Bi
Hi I am trying to do multiple formula's to get a time period between when different things happen. the issue is some of these fields are going to be blank as in they have not be been completed yet so the field is left blank. i would like to create a new column with a time period of days between one date "PLR Job No.Date" - "Booked in Date".
To start with i tried the basic part
calculate(sum('table 1'[booked in date]))-calculate(sum('table 1'[PLR Job No.Date]))"

it was even at this stage which it fails as there is a string.
I would then like to embed it into an if statement stating if the "'table 1'[PLR Job No.Date]" is blank then do the formula - today().


You shouldn't store text in a datetime column, I would say remove "not yet received" from that column, replace text with null and create another column that will store only 2 values "received" & "not received"

In power query, try to replace Not Yet Received to blank and change the data type to date

then create a column
Column = DATEDIFF('Table'[Booked in Date],'Table'[PLR Job No.Date],day)

you can modify the DAX since you didn't mention how to calculate when booked in date is not yet receive and PLR job no.date is null.
